# Django debug toolbar not rendering properly

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm trying to install the django debug toolbar. It does show up, but it renders really weirdly and doesn't match how I've seen it show up for other developers. Also, when I click on the different panel options, nothing happens. Below is a screen shot of what I'm seeing.

[debug toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5wuE.png)

In settings.py I have the following code:

```
    DEBUG = True
    INSTALLED_APPS = [..., 'debug_toolbar', ...]
    MIDDLEWARE = ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', ...other middelware]
    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SQL_WARNING_THRESHOLD': 100,  # milliseconds
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': lambda x: True
    }
    if DEBUG:
        import socket
        hostname, _, ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
        INTERNAL_IPS = [ip[:-1] + "1" for ip in ips] + \
            ['My REMOTE_ADDR', '127.0.0.1']

        import mimetypes
        mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
```

In urls.py, I also have the following:

```
    if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')),
    ]

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I'm using version 4.0 of the debug toolbar. Any suggestions?

Comment: open up a browser dev tools and look for errors in the network tab.

Comment: I am seeing some 404s. All of them are because the key 'debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css' does not exist.

Comment: That's the reason. Check if the files are present on that path. Might be worth reinstalling toolbar or trying another browser